# How to manage alerts for multiple users without deleting?

Tags: 2010, alert

New here and also very new to SharePoint.

I am looking for the best way to manage user and site alerts without deleting them. i.e making changes to the current alerts.

Comment: @ Benny
Thank you for the edit advice

Comment: You're welcome. Do you want to manage users, or alerts or both?

Comment: I would like to manage the list alerts. Is there a way to make changes to the alerts that are already in place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, another user (or administrator) can't edit another users alerts:

> An administrator can view and delete (but not edit) alerts for any users on a site.

Ref: [Alerts Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802949%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

## What you can do is this

Start by going to your list where you have the alert and chose the List tab. In the Share & Track section you find the Alert Me icon and text. Select the arrow to bring up the menu and chose "Manage My Alerts"

[image]

Select the alert you want to manage, in my screenshot it's called "My Alert".

[image]

Then you get the whole list of things you can do to manage your alert. Don't forget to save when your're finished.

[image]

---

To view or delete other users alerts, you need to go to `Site Actions` > `Site Settings` and in the group Site Administration find User alerts:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I have already managed to create alerts for myself and for all the other users, however I wanted to know if there was a way of editing the alerts? i.e to make changes to the settings of the alert.

Comment: @Steve.C Updated my answer at the very top - no it's not possible. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks again Benny, However this option only allows you to delete the desired alerts, not change the settings... It seems that maybe this is not an option?

Comment: Just saw your edit ! Thank you for clearing this up Benny.

Comment: @Steve.C That's correct. You can't edit other users alert - just view and delete. "An administrator can view and delete (but not edit) alerts for any users on a site." [Alerts Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802949(v=office.14).aspx)